# Azure Website Performance - MVC Application Azure Websites

Tags: performance, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am hoping to get some advice as to how i can figure out what is going on with some performance issues i am suffering from.  I have a custom MVC application which is running on Azure Websites in West Europe datacenter.  I have one of our offices trying to connect to the website from Singapore which is where the problem lies.  If i connect to the website myself (from UK) the performance is fast and zippy.  If our Singapore office tries to connect the performance is terribly slow.  Sometimes getting to the initial homepage is slow (i.e. no database connections required for login page).

The page will sometimes just sit and "hang" there.  What i want to know is how can i debug the performance issues with Azure?  What kind of monitoring or performance checks can i do to see if it is a website / sql issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried deploying the app to a datacenter in Asia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Azure New Relic](http://newrelic.com/azure) add in from the market place is very useful. There is a free version which gives you plenty of detail on browser performance and basic sql profiling.

It can provide such details as shown in the screen shot below.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [Application Insights](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/).  It's easy to add to a custom MVC app, and will give you good info to help determine where exactly the issue lies.

[image]
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-detect-triage-diagnose/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Support Site Extension (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/01/new-updates-to-support-site-extension-for-azure-websites/) which would allow you to look at live event logs and HTTP traffic. There are also some more advanced tools for performance issues (i.e. memory dump, event viewer logs). For a deeper dive into debugging in Azure App Service see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4704.

Also as Ben said, Application Insights (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-detect-triage-diagnose/) may help.